# Strange appearance artefact in ActionMenu

Tags: front-end, bugs, gui-construction

I've noticed a strange thing with [`ActionMenu`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ActionMenu.html) which can also be seen in the documentation for V9 and V10 on OS X. It seems that when an `ActionMenu` is grouped with something else in a list a small triangle appears to the right and below:

[image]

This is present throughout my docs. However if I change the default appearance to a popup or button the artefact goes away:

[image]

Anyone have any ideas about the cause of this?

Comment: In Windows 7 I have: http://i.stack.imgur.com/llqh4.png

Comment: @Mr.Wizard interesting. It looks like the "down triangle" on the RHS on Windows gets messed up on Mac. Looks like a bug to me

Comment: @MichaelE2 I just retested an am not seeing it for "PopupMenu", only for the default. I am using V9 this morning on OS X 10.10.1

Comment: @MichaelE2 actually the triangle you are seeing under the popup belongs to the default one to the left. For some reason the triangle appears ~5mm to the right of the default action menu and under the baseline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in the Mathematica FrontEnd that appears on systems running Mac OS X 10.10. The cause is a change, beginning with Yosemite, in the behavior of the API used to draw the popup arrow.  The FrontEnd bug will be fixed in an upcoming release.

Comment: Given you work for WRI in the UI group would you care to comment on this?  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71602/why-do-popupmenus-render-inconsistently-on-macs